# Compiled PHP with pthreads in Debian

Tags: php, pthreads, debian

I compiled PHP-7.0.0RC1 with pthreads in Debian completely without any error according to http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php#114837.

Then I listed PHP Modules with 'php -m ' command and pthread listed there, so it is inistalled correctly.
After that to test it, I used following simple code:

```
<?php
    class cls extends Thread {

    }
?>
```

But I have an error as below:

[image]

and if I remove 'extends Thread' it will run successfully with no error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since this is a release candidate and not a final release, first try the latest RC (which is RC3 at this time of writing, I believe) and if that doesn't help, I suggest you report it to the development team.

Comment: @FrankvanWensveen Thanks I try the latest version php-7.0.0RC4 but again no success, do I have to report and wait untill they respond or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only allowed to load the latest version of pthreads in CLI.

If you aren't getting an error, you aren't using the latest release.

Comment: Is that even possible to use your pthread out of CLI? directly using in our code and run it when user send any request or something like that

Comment: Not possible, or sensible, no.